# Нудно вытащить элемент из bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Мне нужен от bootstrap только navbar. Нужно вытащить с bootstrap только код и стили для navbar. Вроде есть конструкторы для bootstrap но не могу найти.

Comment: Так скачайте bootstrap c офф. страницы, пересмотрите файлы и воспроизведите в ваших отдельных файлах, то что вам надо. А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ Выберите там Navbar... и все..)